# Placing Nodes into a Binary Heap in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

As of now I am giving each Node an id which is used to compare to until the Node with the matching id is found. I need a way to make it more efficient and not have to recursively search through all the Nodes.

I was wondering if there is some math trick to find the right node and have it point to it instead of having to travel through all the nodes to find the right one.

```
    public void insert(int info){
    Node temp = new Node(info, N+1);
    if (this.isEmpty()) { // First item is always the root.
      this.root = temp;
    }
    else{
      balance(temp, root); 
    }
    N++;
  }

public void balance(Node key, Node target){ 
if (key.id == 2*target.id || (key.id == (2*target.id + 1))){
  if (key.id == 2*target.id){
    target.leftChild = key;
    key.parent = target;
    last = key;
  }

  else {
    target.rightChild = key;
    key.parent = target;
    last = key;
  }

  if (key.info < target.info) {
    swim(key);
    return;
  }
}
```

https://pastebin.com/kKhL9ZNh

Comment: Use binary search trees. [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no way around traversing the entire linked list to find a node. That's what makes linked lists, linked lists! The only pointer pointing to a unique node is either the root pointer, or the previous node in the list. If you add previousNode pointers to each node, you can traverse the linked list backwards AND forwards, but that probably won't help your case.

The last thing you might think now is "ok, well what if every node has a pointer to every other node?" And this, would be a form of a complete graph ADT, and not a linked list ADT. If finding specific nodes are your primary goal, then I suggest using an array (or ArrayList) or a Hash Table, but not a Linked List.